# ES6 Template strings: how to nest them?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to nest them like this but I get error. Is there a way ?

```
let greetings1 = 'hello1';
let greetings2 = 'hello2';

let template1 = ``${greetings1}``;
let template2 = ``${greetings2}``;

let template = `${template1}`;
console.log(template);
```

Comment: is there a reason to use 2 back ticks for template1 and 2?

Comment: @Sven.hig I want to put template in an external file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the double quotation marks

```js
let greetings1 = 'hello1';
let greetings2 = 'hello2';

let template1 = `${greetings1}`;
let template2 = `${greetings2}`;

let template = `${template1}`;
console.log(template);
```

Comment: You're right, I think my question doesn't reflect what I wanted though, will think about another one...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```js
let greetings1 = 'hello1';
let greetings2 = 'hello2';

let template = `${greetings1} ${greetings2}`;

console.log(template);
```